# Reverse the order of a list

Tags: python, list, reverse

I need this to reverse what is in the list no mater if its numbers or words right now when I run it, it prints `None`.  I need it to print the reversed list. Can anyone help?

```
def func4(x):
    print(x.reverse())
    return;
e = ['baby','egg','chicken']
func4(e)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is actually working as intended; it reverses the list just fine.  The reason it prints `None` is because `list.reverse` is an in-place method that always returns `None`.

Because of this, you should be calling `reverse` on its own line:

```
def func4(x):
    x.reverse()
    print(x)
e = ['baby','egg','chicken']
func4(e)
```

Now, `print` will print the reversed list instead of the `None` returned by `reverse`.

Note that the same principle applies to `list.append`, `list.extend`, and pretty much all other methods which mutate objects in Python.

Also, I removed the return-statement from the end of your function since it didn't do anything useful.  Python functions already return `None` by default, so there is no reason to explicitly do this.

Answer (score 3):

you can just slice :

```
e = ['baby','egg','chicken']
f = e[::-1]
print(f)
```

Comment: why the downvote? I agree that this is more robust than the `reversed` method ...

Answer (score 2):

`x.reverse()` doesn't return the reversed list, it just reverses it. You need to separately call `print(x)` after you have reversed it.

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach with the "reversed" function:

```
for str in reversed(e):
    print(str)
```